# Result undefined JS. I can't acess this atribute

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I can't get the result of avatar.path , How could I do this ?
If I put this.nome, I receive normally , but I can't get the result of avatar.path.

If I write `this.avatar.name = value` then the following error is thrown:

> (node:6652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'path' of undefined

I need get `avatar.path`, because I will use for return URL

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    nome: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    },
    email: {`enter code here`
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    passwordresetoken: {
      type: String,
      select: false
    },
    passwordresetexpires: {
      type: Date,
      select: false
    },
    usuario_validado: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    cpf: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    user_cuidador: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    avatar: [
      {
        nome: {
          type: String
        },
        path: { type: String, required: true }
      }
    ],
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  },
  {
    toObject: {
      getters: true,
      setter: true,
      virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
      getters: true,
      setter: true,
      virtuals: true
    }
  }
);


UserSchema.virtual("url").get(function() {
  console.log(this.nome); // I receive right the name
  console.log(this.avatar); // I receive undefined

  // I need to return avatar.path 
  return `http://localhost:300/files/${this.nome}`; // I can receive all the names right. But, I need avatar.path
});
```

Comment: hey.. can you see `enter code here` on line 7?...

Comment: I can't see any code

Answer (score 0):

`avatar` is an array of

```
{
  nome: {
    type: String
  },
  path: { type: String, required: true }
}
```

as defined by

```
avatar: [
  {
    nome: {
      type: String
    },
    path: { type: String, required: true }
  }
],
```

It can also be `undefined`.

You are treating it like an object here: `this.avatar.name = value`.

If the assumption is that it will always be an array of 1, then convert it into an object:

```
avatar: {
    nome: {
      type: String
    },
    path: { type: String, required: true }
  },
```

and make sure to null/undefined check in your virtual. If you need the avatar to always be present, then if memory serves, you can make the avatar a schema and require it.

```
const AvatarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  nome: {
    type: String
  },
  path: { type: String, required: true }
})
```

and then inside of your `UserSchema`, you'd reference it:

```
avatar: { type: AvatarSchema, required: true }
```

Otherwise you'll need to null/undefined check:

```
UserSchema.virtual("url").get(function() {
  console.log(this.nome); // I receive right the name
  console.log(this.avatar); // I receive undefined

  // if avatar is an array then I guess you just want the first one?
  let avatarPath;
  if(this.avatar && this.avatar.length) {
    avatarPath = this.avatar[0].path
  } 
  // ... 

  return avatarPath ? avatarPath : `http://localhost:300/files/${this.nome}`; 
});
```

If you keep your schema as is and try would like to set the avatar path, then you'd do something like this:

```
this.avatar = this.avatar || []
this.avatar.push({name: value})
// but it will fail to validate because path is required.
```

Check the docs for [mongoose subdocs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

### Edit:

I forgot to mention that you in your question, you refer to `this.avatar.name` but your schema refers to `nome` and not `name`